# How do I replace an id tag inside a div if seen in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have this html line

I am trying to make it so that when IE reads that line, it changes the "listHr" id to "listhrIE".
I have tried this, in an attempt to switch out the line altogeather, but no luck:

```
<hr id="listHr"></hr> <!--[if IE]><id="listHrIE"></hr><![endif]-->
```

I am sure I am doing this wrong. What is the correct way of doing this?
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `<id="listHrIE"></hr>` should be `<hr id="listHrIE" />`.

Comment: Also `<hr/> are self-closing.

Comment: Are you trying to target ALL versions of IE? In general, Browser detection is not the best method and should be avoided. This is especially true on newer version of IE that are standards compliant. Instead, use feature detection, which is much more future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

IE tags have a "not IE" component.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<hr id="listHrIE"></hr>
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
<hr id="listHr"></hr>
<![endif]>
```

However I'd offer a better way to do it would be to just override the style of `listHr` when IE is detected

As @Paulie_D pointed out: conditional tags are deprecated and won't work for IE 10 and above. You can use a special meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

to force them to work however this is not recommended. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Under IE10 only I presume?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I assume it works as long as IE 10 still has support for the proprietary tags.

Comment: I think conditional tags were lost after Ie9

Comment: "As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode." -[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IE only conditional tags to detect IE.

Just like:

```
<!--[if IE ]>
<p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

So, In your case you need two things to change ID.

1) Display IE only ID

2) Hide non-IE ID

To apply IE only ID you need following conditional tag code

```
<!--[if IE ]>
<div id="listHrIE"></hr>
<![endif]-->
```

To hide non-IE ID you need to add `display:none`

```
<!--[if IE ]>
<div id="listHrIE"></div>
<div id="listHr" style="display:none"></div>
<![endif]-->
```

Now you can style your IE Only ID in way you want and it will only replace listHr when IE detects.

**Update: To target IE 10 Use following jQuery: Before using add jQuery Migrate**

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>` This line

to your page`<head>`
Then add

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
$("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try these:

```
<!--[if !IE]><hr id="listHr"></hr><!-->

<!--[if IE]><hr id="listHrIE"></hr><!-->
```

if you want set this id for some version of IE, you can do this:

greater and equal IE8:

```
 <!--[if gte IE 8]><!-->
```

less and equal IE8:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><!-->
```

equal IE8:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><!-->
```